# Datasets in NLP research papers

Tags: data-mining, nlp, dataset, text-mining

I am looking for a dataset containing a large number of NLP research papers and abstracts. Are there any open access datasets like that?

If so, can you please share the details?

Answer (score 1):

I have come across such a [dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/master/data/arvix_abstracts.txt) in [CS 20SI GitHub repo](https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials): it's a collection of abstracts from 7200 research papers.

If you need even more, you can always write a simple crawler of [arXiv web-site](https://arxiv.org/). The abstracts are outlined right on the webpage in a `<blockquote>` tag, no need to download and parse a pdf.

Comment: link of dataset is dead